# Как сделать пропуск ошибок в gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Есть gulpfile.js, он работает хорошо, но есть одно но. При любой ошибке в less, нужно перезапускать `gulp watch`. Подскажите, как это исправить?

```
    var gulp                = require('gulp'),
    less                = require('gulp-less'), //подключаем препроцессор LESS
    browserSync         = require('browser-sync'), //Подключаем Browser Sync
    concat              = require('gulp-concat'), // Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
    uglify              = require('gulp-uglifyjs'), // Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
    cssnano             = require('gulp-cssnano'),  // Подключаем пакет для минификации CSS
    rename              = require('gulp-rename'); // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
    del                 = require('del'), // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок
    imagemin            = require('gulp-imagemin'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с изображениями
    pngquant            = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с png
    cache               = require('gulp-cache'), // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования
    autoprefixer        = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),// Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов
    smartgrid           = require('smart-grid'),
    gcmq                = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
    plumber             = require('gulp-plumber'),
    cleanCSS            = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    sourcemaps          = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    connect             = require('gulp-connect-php');



gulp.task('default',  function (){      
    console.log('Введите функцию.');
    }); 


gulp.task('connect', function(callback) {
  connect.server({
    port: 8001
  }, callback);
});


gulp.task('browser-sync', ['connect'], function(){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'project'
        },
        notify: false,
    });
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('build/less/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())       
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) //Включаем автопрефиксы
    .pipe(gcmq()) //Группируем медиазапросы
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project/css')) 
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'build/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',     
        'build/libs/jquery.mask.min.js',
        'build/libs/owl.carousel.min.js'                            
        ])  
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project/js'));
});

gulp.task('css-libs', ['less'], function(){
    return gulp.src('project/css/libs.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())    
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project/css/'));
});



gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function() {    
    gulp.watch('build/less/*.less', ['less']);
    gulp.watch('project/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('project/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('project/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('project/fonts/*', browserSync.reload);

});
```

P.S. скрин ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Перенеси `plumber()` выше, что бы он перехватывал ошибки `less()`

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('build/less/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) //Включаем автопрефиксы
    .pipe(gcmq()) //Группируем медиазапросы
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project/css')) 
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});
```

Comment: Да, это решило проблему, но сейчас он выкидывает ошибку в консоль, при этом приходится перезапускать watcher. Скрин сейчас приложу в вопросе. Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Так он как бы намекает, что есть ошибка (видимо нет `;` после `left: 0`) ... достаточно поправить ошибку и сохранить файл, перезапускать вотчер не требуется.

Comment: В этом, к сожалению, и проблема, что добавляя `;` и сохраняя файл, ничего не меняется :(

Comment: @Alexxosipov, хммм, попробуй обновить все что используется для билда css файлов. Сложно сказать что именно ему не нравится, можешь скинуть свой css который он пытается автопрефиксить, гляну что там к чему.

Comment: Убрал return из таска, все заработало, хотя очень странно

Comment: Прикольно xDD Никогда не использую в gulp return, не знаю как он работает, но рад, что починилось ))

Comment: Спасибо)) Кстати, еще по этой теме вопрос. Не подскажешь, как эту ошибку в браузер вынести? Как сделать проверку на наличие ошибки в таске less? Чтобы потом через `browserSync.notify()` ее в браузер скинуть

Comment: Не, никогда не задавался таким вопросом, надо погуглить, задумка интересная, так как не всегда сразу понимаешь, что плюмбер ошибку выплюнул.

Comment: Как в browserSync вывести не нашел, сразу наткнулся на gulp-notify (системными сообщения отображает) .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))

Comment: Оу, вот это круто, спасибо)))